# jQuery colliding with ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

We have an application that uses ASP.NET 4 with the AJAX control toolkit.
We also use jQuery in a few parts of app, so it was initially added to the ScriptManager trag in the master page like so:

```
<asp:ScriptManager...
   <Scripts>
     <asp:ScriptReference PATH="...google's jquery CDN ...
```

This worked. But in an effort to optimize our site, we've tried to move a bunch of our script tags to the head tag, thinking about combining and minifying later. But when I add it to the head like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="googles jquery CDN..."
```

The javascript throws strange errors like 'Sys is not defined' from scripts where we using the AJAX Sys object. Note: we only get erros from script A, if script A itself is moved from the ScriptManager tag to the head tag, and only if script A uses the Microsoft AJAX objects.

Is this a jQuery scoping issue, or something weird that the ScriptManager control was doing for me?

Comment: '... is not defined' usualy means you are trying to use objs before they are declared.  Since you are moving the tags where you load jQuery I'm going to go on a limb here and say they are not loaded when your code is trying to use them.  Look at the HTML output and find where jQuery is loaded.

Comment: that turned out to be it. answer the question so I can close it.